# Oracle SQL: Case Statement in where clause returns an error "single-row subquery returns more than one row"

Tags: sql, oracle, select, case, where-clause

Here is a select query's where clause with a CASE condition statement. I have written this for satisfying the following requirement: "In case of any weekday, the result would contain the date of the next day and in case of Friday the result would include the dates of Saturday, Sunday and Monday"

```
where DTTM IN (case 
                      when to_char(sysdate,'day') <> 'friday   ' then to_date(sysdate+1,'DD/MON/YY')
                      else (select to_date(sysdate+1,'DD/MM/YYYY') + level - 1 ddate
                            from dual
                            connect by level <= to_date(sysdate+4,'DD/MM/YYYY') - to_date(sysdate+1,'DD/MM/YYYY')
                            )
                end)
```

I have used **IN** too, but I am getting an error

> ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row
>
> 1427. 00000 -  "single-row subquery returns more than one row"

Please help me resolve this error.

Here is the complete query for your reference:

```
      select * from orders 
      where DTTM IN (case 
                                when to_char(sysdate,'day') <> 'friday   ' then to_date(sysdate+1,'DD/MON/YY')
                                else (select to_date(sysdate+1,'DD/MM/YYYY') + level - 1 ddate
                                      from dual
                                      connect by level <= to_date(sysdate+4,'DD/MM/YYYY') - to_date(sysdate+1,'DD/MM/YYYY')
                                      )
                                end) 
      order by  DTTM;
```

Comment: A `CASE` statement can only return a scalar (a single value).  The solution is to change the subquery to return a single row.  Can you include the full query so that we see the entire logic?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thanks. But how to get a list of dates in return? Or is there any other way to meet the requirement, without using CASE?

Comment: That's a case expression. (A case expression returns a value. A case statement (e.g. in stored procedures) is just conditional execution of code.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following solution.

```
SELECT * FROM orders 
WHERE dttm = to_date(SYSDATE+1,'DD/MON/YY')
AND TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'day') <> 'friday'
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM orders 
where dttm IN (SELECT TO_DATE(SYSDATE+1,'DD/MM/YYYY') + level - 1 ddate
               FROM dual
               CONNECT BY LEVEL <= to_date(sysdate+4,'DD/MM/YYYY') - to_date(sysdate+1,'DD/MM/YYYY')
               )
AND to_char(sysdate,'day') = 'friday'
```

The first query will run in case it is not a Friday. If it is Friday then it will not return any results. The query after UNION ALL will run only on a Friday. Only of the queries will return a result.